# no suitable method found to override error in umbraco razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, umbraco

In my umbraco website I am trying to access a function through razor script.
Function is written in C#, compiled and added dll to my umbraco website.

```
 public static XPathNodeIterator GetProductsFromId(string Id)
 {
     XPathNodeIterator items;

         string asd= string.Concat("product", Id);
         if (HttpContext.Current.Items[asd] == null)
         {
             XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
             HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(asd, xmlDocument.CreateNavigator().Select("."));
         }
         items = (XPathNodeIterator)HttpContext.Current.Items[asd];

     return items;
 }
```

and in my razor I am trying to acces this function like this

```
@inherits common.Web.blogic
@{
    System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator v = GetProductsFromId("123456");   
}
```

I believe I had done everything right but it creates an error likes this

> Error loading Razor Script TestRazor.cshtml
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2928d574\d747540e\App_Web_testrazor.cshtml.70df5e80.zwangvtf.0.cs(43): error CS0115: 'ASP._Page_macroScripts_TestRazor_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you require the `@inherits common.Web.blogic` is it the container that has the implementation for the `GetProductsFromId("123456");`. IF this is the case, you have to use only like this

> @using common.Web.blogic

instead of using `inherits`.

Please Share your updates on this post.